# How to insert schema file into mysql under bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to insert schema file content into the MySQL database as a single field via mysql command under bash. It is easy to do under mysql command line. But my case is that I want to use it together with several dynamic variables. Code is looks like below: (i is the index of services)

```
    WSDL=`cat ${WSDL_FILE}`
    WADL=`cat ${WADL_FILE}`
    XSD=`cat ${XSD_FILE}`

    ADD_SERVICE=$(eval echo "insert into Services set Name=\'\${SRV_LIST_${i}}\', Description=\'\${SRV_LIST_${i}_Description}\', Version=\'\${SRV_LIST_${i}_Version}\', Status=\'Active\', WSDL=\'\'\'${WSDL}\'\'\', WADL=\'\'\'${WADL}\'\'\', XSD=\'\'\'${XSD}\'\'\', CreatedBy=\'${USER}\', CreatedOn=NOW\(\), CreatedAt=\'${HOSTNAME}\';")
    Result=$(mysql -umysql -pmysqlpasswd -D service_reg -e "${ADD_SERVICE}")
```

The result would be like below:

```
./ServiceRegistry.sh: eval: line 279: syntax error near  unexpected token `newline'
./ServiceRegistry.sh: eval: line 279: `echo insert into Services set Name=\'${SRV_LIST_1}\', Description=\'${SRV_LIST_1_Description}\', Version=\'${SRV_LIST_1_Version}\', Status=\'Active\', WSDL=\'\', WADL=\'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

But if I set WSDL, WADL and XSD to empty string, it works fine.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You know, in this case the `LOAD DATA INFILE` method might be easier. Also, `INSERT INTO` with `SET` is an oddity you don't often see.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the culprit

```
WADL=\'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

The double quotes aren't escaped and the string prematurely terminated and reopened. Maybe, there are even more quotes down the road.